# Code is breaking on a line and is not being caught by a try-catch. How do I fix this?

Tags: c#, exception, system.net.mail

I am trying to send an email using System.Net.Mail. On SmtpClient.Send(message) the code is breaking but the exception is not being caught.

I have tried using the SendAsync function and currently I have set symbols to load from microsoft in case that was the issue. This is on the local server so I expect to catch an error that the mail failed to send, but not for it to break.

```
public void Send()
        {
            try
            {
                var smptClient = new SmtpClient("appgw.flex.com");
                smptClient.Send(Message);
                Log.Debug("Successfully sent email");
            }
            catch (Excpetion e) {
                Log.Debug("Excpeption in Mail.Send: ");
                Log.Debug(e.Message);
            }
        }
```

Debug Output:

```
'OverClockedClient.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OverClockedClient.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\aurssmit\source\repos\OverClocked\OverClockedClient\OverClockedClient\bin\Debug\OverClockedClient.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OverClockedClient.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: OverClockedClient.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Net.Http\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Net.Http.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OverClockedClient.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: OverClockedClient.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OverClockedClient.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: OverClockedClient.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OverClockedClient.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: OverClockedClient.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OverClockedClient.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: OverClockedClient.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Domain 2): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Caching\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.Caching.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Caching\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.Caching.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in mscorlib.dll
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Exception thrown: 'System.Globalization.CultureNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Globalization.CultureNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.JScript\v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.JScript.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\Users\aurssmit\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fca63132\91201cbe\assembly\dl3\403d1e26\00637264_8ef3d301\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader\v4.0_1.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\Users\aurssmit\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fca63132\91201cbe\assembly\dl3\91e34262\000cf304_819bd301\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\Users\aurssmit\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fca63132\91201cbe\assembly\dl3\b162fac5\000cf304_819bd301\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\Users\aurssmit\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fca63132\91201cbe\assembly\dl3\25cc7e53\00a488f2_331fd201\WebActivatorEx.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\Users\aurssmit\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fca63132\91201cbe\assembly\dl3\312e7e86\0016727c_6727cf01\System.Web.Optimization.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\Users\aurssmit\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fca63132\91201cbe\assembly\dl3\8bd8f580\00d89767_809bd301\System.Web.Mvc.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\Users\aurssmit\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fca63132\91201cbe\assembly\dl3\4c8f9e77\00a127c9_a1afd401\Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\Users\aurssmit\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fca63132\91201cbe\assembly\dl3\49437c71\000cf304_819bd301\System.Web.WebPages.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Page Inspector\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\Users\aurssmit\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fca63132\91201cbe\assembly\dl3\59409813\008c5861_856acd01\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\Users\aurssmit\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fca63132\91201cbe\assembly\dl3\d8bd35c4\00c2c934_4c8bd401\AdvancedStringBuilder.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\Users\aurssmit\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fca63132\91201cbe\assembly\dl3\b77571e9\00386ccf_6caece01\Antlr3.Runtime.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\Users\aurssmit\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fca63132\91201cbe\assembly\dl3\96235f14\001791e0_e196d401\ClosedXML.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\Users\aurssmit\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fca63132\91201cbe\assembly\dl3\e3f3b510\00c9f671_42dfd201\DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\Users\aurssmit\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fca63132\91201cbe\assembly\dl3\030b1ce7\00ff87e1_2a4cd301\EntityFramework.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\Users\aurssmit\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fca63132\91201cbe\assembly\dl3\b36f2f77\002cb9e2_2a4cd301\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\Users\aurssmit\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fca63132\91201cbe\assembly\dl3\3e6533c1\00f41bc5_6e64d301\ExcelNumberFormat.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\Users\aurssmit\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fca63132\91201cbe\assembly\dl3\145f71e6\001e136f_3eb5d301\FastMember.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\Users\aurssmit\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fca63132\91201cbe\assembly\dl3\0c8e568e\00abf447_4a0bd501\JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.ChakraCore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\Users\aurssmit\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fca63132\91201cbe\assembly\dl3\ffd220d0\0042b0dd_fc01d501\JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Core.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\Users\aurssmit\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fca63132\91201cbe\assembly\dl3\e9b93649\0035a137_b3a4d401\JSPool.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\Users\aurssmit\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fca63132\91201cbe\assembly\dl3\4290c5b0\00731429_7498d201\log4net.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\Users\aurssmit\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fca63132\91201cbe\assembly\dl3\a98d8bf5\0007e0e1_49f0d201\Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\Users\aurssmit\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fca63132\91201cbe\assembly\dl3\b65083c8\00df3bbd_a1afd401\Microsoft.Owin.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\Users\aurssmit\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fca63132\91201cbe\assembly\dl3\cf6411ae\00df3bbd_a1afd401\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\Users\aurssmit\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fca63132\91201cbe\assembly\dl3\14bfdab3\006313d5_a1afd401\Microsoft.Owin.Security.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\Users\aurssmit\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fca63132\91201cbe\assembly\dl3\e9184c03\00821dcf_a1afd401\Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.dll'. Symbols loaded.
The thread 0x1d680 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\Users\aurssmit\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fca63132\91201cbe\assembly\dl3\c4148420\00f7c809_c7a8d301\Newtonsoft.Json.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\Users\aurssmit\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fca63132\91201cbe\assembly\dl3\085a5080\3df01f67_4f16d501\OverClocked.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\Users\aurssmit\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fca63132\91201cbe\assembly\dl3\704adcab\00bf7f6e_cbc1cd01\Owin.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\Users\aurssmit\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fca63132\91201cbe\assembly\dl3\37f0f47b\007dda62_11dbd401\React.Core.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\Users\aurssmit\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fca63132\91201cbe\assembly\dl3\da26c9e9\007dda62_11dbd401\React.Web.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\Users\aurssmit\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fca63132\91201cbe\assembly\dl3\2b757438\007dda62_11dbd401\React.Web.Mvc4.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\Users\aurssmit\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fca63132\91201cbe\assembly\dl3\e6ce11ff\00e929bd_60c4d101\System.Buffers.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\Users\aurssmit\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fca63132\91201cbe\assembly\dl3\7fb5c252\00010ce7_9f00d301\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\Users\aurssmit\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fca63132\91201cbe\assembly\dl3\47127f9b\00e66dd1_60c4d101\System.IO.Packaging.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\Users\aurssmit\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fca63132\91201cbe\assembly\dl3\e7ea25cd\00a23ba5_4c87d401\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\Users\aurssmit\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fca63132\91201cbe\assembly\dl3\fc8791f6\000cf304_819bd301\System.Web.Helpers.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\Users\aurssmit\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fca63132\91201cbe\assembly\dl3\58e87c34\00be89b3_4c87d401\System.Web.Http.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\Users\aurssmit\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fca63132\91201cbe\assembly\dl3\e727e53e\00f0adf8_4c87d401\System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll'. Symbols loaded.
The thread 0x1b1bc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x17aa4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\Users\aurssmit\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fca63132\91201cbe\assembly\dl3\f6f48814\007dda62_11dbd401\System.Web.Optimization.React.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\Users\aurssmit\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fca63132\91201cbe\assembly\dl3\39d9c0fe\00f4e575_809bd301\System.Web.Razor.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\Users\aurssmit\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fca63132\91201cbe\assembly\dl3\2605ad13\002397f9_6c18cf01\WebGrease.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Resources.ResourceManager\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\Users\aurssmit\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fca63132\91201cbe\App_global.asax.4chzafm8.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activation\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activation.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Page Inspector\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Tracing.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Exception thrown: 'System.Web.HttpException' in System.Web.dll
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Net.Http\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Net.Http.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\SMDiagnostics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\SMDiagnostics.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Internals\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Activities.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activities.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.WorkflowServices.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.DynamicData\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.DynamicData.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xaml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xaml.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.Linq.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Numerics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Numerics.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data.OracleClient\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.OracleClient.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Transactions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.DirectoryServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.DirectoryServices.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-OverClocked'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mobile\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Mobile.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.RegularExpressions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.RegularExpressions.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.RegularExpressions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.RegularExpressions.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\Users\aurssmit\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fca63132\91201cbe\App_Web_f4utfse4.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\Users\aurssmit\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fca63132\91201cbe\App_Web_deff3z1w.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Dynamic\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Dynamic.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' in Microsoft.CSharp.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' in Microsoft.CSharp.dll
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\Users\aurssmit\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fca63132\91201cbe\App_Web_nu41df0q.dll'. 
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' in Microsoft.CSharp.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' in Microsoft.CSharp.dll
The thread 0x1ded8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Threading\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Threading.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Diagnostics.Debug\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036307637739608): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Diagnostics.Tracing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll'. Symbols loaded.
The thread 0x87c8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1da7c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1d028 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1d194 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1dd50 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1dfcc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1d5ec has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1dc50 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1bdc8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1d218 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1a5f0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1d568 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[81656] OverClockedClient.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
The program '[118156] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

Comment: Is the `catch (Excpetion e)` just a typo, or is this your actual code?

Comment: `RuntimeBinderException` suggests a problem with a value of type `dynamic` (for instance you try to use a property that doesn't exist). Do you have any, such as ViewData in MVC?

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
catch (Excpetion e) {
```

when you should have

```
catch (Exception e) {
```

(you swapped around the p and e)

Comment: Sorry that actually must've happened when I posted, but in my code it is spelled correctly and generating these results.